# Как проверять атрибуты (разрешения) доступа к директории?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне необходимо проверить доступ к директории (разрешения для групп), на Windows 8.1/10.
Суть в том, что вполне возможна ситуация, когда все разрешения или их часть стоят в запрете и, в данном случаи, я не хочу кидать *expection*, и тем более с *errno*.

Пример:

[image: ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED_SAMPLE_SCREENSHOT]

*Необходимо заранее понять*, функция(и), которая покажет будет ли у меня при чтении/записи `WinError` или `PermissionError`, для определенной группы или всех групп (`СИСТЕМА`/`Администратор` и т.д).

Стандартная библиотека `stat` и `os.access()`, не дали мне нужных результатов.
Также встречаются варианты со сменой прав для директории, но это не всегда может сработать, особенно в `usermode`, именно поэтому я пытаюсь сделать именно проверку.

Такие выводы были сделаны примерно из следующего кода (*я точно так проверял? Не знаю.*), и игры с параметрами безопасности директории (*я также менял и само расположение директории, на `рабочий стол`, `мои документы`, `%appdata%` и прочие пространства, предназначенных для пользовательских данных [Все что в `C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\`]. Думал, возможно в этом ошибка.*), что выдавало всегда одинаковый результат (*возможно, иногда незначительно отличающийся, но вопрос это не отменяет*). 
Самое главное, что выпадет *Exception*, если что-либо попробовать сделать с данной директорией, что не дозволенно установленными правилами, и выполнять таким образом:

**Исходники:**

```py
import os
import stat

def access(path, flag): return os.access(path, flag)
def isExists(path): return access(path, os.F_OK)
def isReadable(path): return access(path, os.R_OK)
def isWritable(path): return access(path, os.W_OK)
def isExecuteable(path): return access(path, os.X_OK)

def mstat(path, followsymlink = 1):
    if isinstance(path, str):
        info = os.stat(path)
        if followsymlink and stat.S_ISLNK(info[stat.ST_MODE]):
            return(os.lstat(path))
        return(info)
    return(os.fstat(path))

def _mode(path): return(mstat(path)[stat.ST_MODE])

def mode(path):   return(stat.S_IMODE(_mode(path)))
def ifreg(path):  return(stat.S_ISREG(_mode(path)))
def ifdir(path):  return(stat.S_ISDIR(_mode(path)))
def ifchr(path):  return(stat.S_ISCHR(_mode(path)))
def ifblk(path):  return(stat.S_ISBLK(_mode(path)))
def iffifo(path): return(stat.S_ISFIFO(_mode(path)))
def iflnk(path):  return(stat.S_ISLNK(_mode(path)))
def ifsock(path): return(stat.S_ISSOCK(_mode(path)))

def is_suid(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_ISUID == stat.S_ISUID)
def is_sgid(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_ISGID == stat.S_ISGID)
def is_svtx(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_ISVTX == stat.S_ISVTX)
def is_read(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IREAD == stat.S_IREAD)
def is_write(path): return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IWRITE == stat.S_IWRITE)
def is_exec(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IEXEC == stat.S_IEXEC)
def is_rwxu(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRWXU == stat.S_IRWXU)
def is_rusr(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRUSR == stat.S_IRUSR)
def is_wusr(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IWUSR == stat.S_IWUSR)
def is_xusr(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IXUSR == stat.S_IXUSR)
def is_rwxg(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRWXG == stat.S_IRWXG)
def is_rgrp(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRGRP == stat.S_IRGRP)
def is_wgrp(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IWGRP == stat.S_IWGRP)
def is_xgrp(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IXGRP == stat.S_IXGRP)
def is_rwxo(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IRWXO == stat.S_IRWXO)
def is_roth(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IROTH == stat.S_IROTH)
def is_woth(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IWOTH == stat.S_IWOTH)
def is_xoth(path):  return(_mode(path) & stat.S_IXOTH == stat.S_IXOTH)

path = 'C:\\ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED_SAMPLE'

print(f'''
    mode    = {mode(path)}
    ifreg   = {ifreg(path)}
    ifdir   = {ifdir(path)}
    ifchr   = {ifchr(path)}
    ifblk   = {ifblk(path)}
    iffifo  = {iffifo(path)}
    iflnk   = {iflnk(path)}
    ifsock  = {ifsock(path)}
    is_suid = {is_suid(path)}
    is_sgid = {is_sgid(path)}
    is_svtx = {is_svtx(path)}
    is_read = {is_read(path)}
    is_write = {is_write(path)}
    is_exec = {is_exec(path)}
    is_rwxu = {is_rwxu(path)}
    is_rusr = {is_rusr(path)}
    is_wusr = {is_wusr(path)}
    is_xusr = {is_xusr(path)}
    is_rwxg = {is_rwxg(path)}
    is_rgrp = {is_rgrp(path)}
    is_wgrp = {is_wgrp(path)}
    is_xgrp = {is_xgrp(path)}
    is_rwxo = {is_rwxo(path)}
    is_roth = {is_roth(path)}
    is_woth = {is_woth(path)}
    is_xoth = {is_xoth(path)}
    isExists      = {isExists(path)}
    isReadable    = {isReadable(path)}
    isWritable    = {isWritable(path)}
    isExecuteable = {isExecuteable(path)}
''')
```

**Вывод:**

```py
    mode    = 511
    ifreg   = False
    ifdir   = True
    ifchr   = False
    ifblk   = False
    iffifo  = False
    iflnk   = False
    ifsock  = False
    is_suid = False
    is_sgid = False
    is_svtx = False
    is_read = True
    is_write = True
    is_exec = True
    is_rwxu = True
    is_rusr = True
    is_wusr = True
    is_xusr = True
    is_rwxg = True
    is_rgrp = True
    is_wgrp = True
    is_xgrp = True
    is_rwxo = True
    is_roth = True
    is_woth = True
    is_xoth = True
    isExists      = True
    isReadable    = True
    isWritable    = True
    isExecuteable = True
```

Я думал попробовать `win32api`, но у меня он не завелся, поэтому хотелось бы видеть *Pure Python* в виде ответа.

Меня также вполне устроил бы вариант с использование PowerShell/Batchfile и дальнейшим экспортом этого добра в Python. Ну или на крайний случай сделать `dll`.
Буду думать в этом направлении, но надеюсь найдется ответ для Pure Python.

Я не исключаю вашей мысли, что лучше не париться и бросить `exception` или *а зачем это тебе вообще?* или *так вообще не делают*, но это мой интерес с точки зрения изучения, проблема, возникшая из желания.

Comment: Так а просто прогонять команду через cmd (icacl) или powershall (get-acl) чем не подходит?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev если бы я знал про такое, я же поэтому и спрашиваю. Попробую. Порой гуглинг выходит корявый, уж извините) Но мне желательно в Python все таки, но думаю все можно красиво прикрутить, если это работает

Comment: Сейчас напишу, там в 2 строчки то решение)

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, или вам не нужно кидать исключение, или вам нужен способ для определения доступов к каталогу-файлу. Пока ваш вопрос представляет собой несвязанный поток сознания.

Comment: @sanmai чтобы определить можно ли что-либо сделать всегда кидают исключение? Интересный у вас подход. "способ для определения доступов к каталогу-файлу." Например API ntfs, который я абсолютно не знаю, может быть там есть функция, что вернет мне bool, нет, ну так, как идея? Я думаю что такое возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",
              '(Get-Acl _dir_).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "_usergroup_"} | select -ExpandProperty filesystemrights'],
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

Описание возвращаемых прав доступа (названия идентичны правам на вкладке `безопасность` в свойстве папки) можно посмотреть [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Если надо сохранить результат в некую переменную, то:

1. `stdout = sys.stdout` -> `stdout = PIPE`
2. `out = p.communicate()[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не хотите кидать исключения при отсутствии доступа к файлам или каталогом, которое невозможно выяснить заранее используя обычный функции проверки доступа, то, как вариант, можно сделать свою обёртку для используемого API, которая будет заменять метод, или только замену для одной функции где возникает исключение, ловить его, и возвращать ошибку без пересылки исключения выше по стеку. Такой вариант должен работать быстрее, чем вызов `Popen` для создания отдельного процесса PowerShell для проверки доступов.

Пример замены через [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) функции `os.rmdir` на свою имплементацию:

```py
import os

orig_rmdir = os.rmdir

def my_rmdir(path):
    try:
        orig_rmdir(path)
        print("Directory '%s' has been removed successfully" %path)
    except PermissionError as error:
        print("Error found: %s" %error)
        pass

os.rmdir = my_rmdir

os.mkdir('foo')
os.rmdir('foo')
```

Замена модуля на свой под системным именем:

```py
import my_os as os
```

Comment: Звучит интересно, а не могли бы вы показать пример такого действия?

Comment: С удовольствием, если вы покажите пример кода, где у вас исключение.

Comment: например, банальный os.rmdir() -> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе:

Comment: @sanmai `pass` вроде забыли в `except-е`

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev спасибо

Comment: "...в данном случаи, я не хочу кидать expection, и тем более с errno..."

Comment: Вы не кидаете, исключение не уходит за пределы этой функции.

Comment: @sanmai задача в том, чтобы не писать exception, нигде.

Comment: Нужно быть телепатом, чтобы догадаться об этом из исходной задачи. Простите ради бога!

Comment: "Необходимо заранее понять, функция(и), которая покажет будет ли у меня при чтении/записи WinError или PermissionError, для определенной группы или всех групп (СИСТЕМА/Администратор и т.д)."

Comment: Вопрос начинается у вас с  "Мне необходимо проверить доступ к директории (разрешения для групп), на Windows 8.1/10. Суть в том, что вполне возможна ситуация, когда все разрешения или их часть стоят в запрете и, в данном случаи, я не хочу кидать expection, и тем более с errno" - мое решение отвечает этим требованиям. Вам нужно переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: @sanmai поэтому вас с коде есть exception,хотя я прошу его не делать, ни в каком виде.